# `vi` command doesn't open newly installed Vim 7.4 on OS X

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I just installed Vim 7.4 on my MacBook using Homebrew. When I enter `vim` on the command line, it successfully enters Vim 7.4, but when I use `vi` I still get the old 7.3.

To install Vim 7.4 I used this command:

```
brew install vim --override-system-vi
```

When I do which:

```
$ which vi
/usr/local/bin/vi
```

When I execute this path in my shell `/usr/local/bin/vi` it does open 7.4. So I thought it might be an alias, but `alias vi` didn't find anything.

I'm quite puzzled by this and I have no idea why this happens. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it? I could of course make an alias of `vi` to `vim` but I wonder why it works the way it does right now.

Comment: What does `type vi` tell you?

Comment: @slhck Thanks, that helped me! I found the problem now, see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you change paths, or install new binaries, you should always:

- restart your shell, or
- rehash the loaded binaries (e.g. in Bash with `hash -r` or Zsh with `rehash`)

Answer (score 3):

Dependancies

- Install XCode from the App Store
- Run XCode and agree to the License Agreement on first-run

Then you can `brew install vim --override-system-vi` successfully.
Then 
try running `mvim -v` or better yet aliasing vi and or vim to `mvim -v` in your `~/.bash_profile`. It's an easy way out. Running plain `mvim` will launch a GUI vim, but with the `-v` flag you get to run in vim in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently.

While using Git (eg. `git commit`), it calls system vim (vim 7.3 OS X 10.11), but that vim doesn't works well with my spf13-vim settings.

I tried these:

```
brew uninstall vim
brew install vim --override-system-vi --with-python3 --with-lua
```

and **restart my shell**. (I guess that's the problem in your case.)

then it works.

---

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/vim.rb